# Symfony TwigBundle not loading any custom extensions

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, twig, symfony4, twig-extension

I am working on updating [Zikula](https://github.com/zikula/core) from Symfony 3 to Symfony 4 (I'm working specifically in [this PR](https://github.com/zikula/core/pull/3991) at the moment). Part of this is removing Symfony's old *templating* mechanism and switching entirely to Twig. In the process I am running into a very unusual problem: None of the custom Twig extensions in the [included Bundles](https://github.com/zikula/core/tree/master/src/lib/Zikula/Bundle) or the [pseudo bundles](https://github.com/zikula/core/tree/master/src/system) (they're just Bundles named Modules) are loaded and available in templates.

**Yes**, the extensions class are autowired and autoloaded and **yes** they are available - i.e. they are listed in `bin/console debug:container` and specifically if I do something like

```
me% bin/console debug:container AdminExtension

Information for Service "Zikula\AdminModule\Twig\Extension\AdminExtension"
==========================================================================

 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                             
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       Zikula\AdminModule\Twig\Extension\AdminExtension  
  Class            Zikula\AdminModule\Twig\Extension\AdminExtension  
  Tags             twig.extension                                    
  Public           no                                                
  Synthetic        no                                                
  Lazy             no                                                
  Shared           yes                                               
  Abstract         no                                                
  Autowired        yes                                               
  Autoconfigured   yes                                               
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------- 

 ! [NOTE] The "Zikula\AdminModule\Twig\Extension\AdminExtension" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the  
 !        container was compiled.
```

This clearly shows that not only is the service properly autowired, but it is also tagged correctly.

If I do `bin/console debug:twig` **none** of the custom extensions are listed (at the top with functions, filters, etc). I even tried to step through the [TwigBundle Compiler](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bundle/blob/a684f9439ed7ed910d168fa6b6b246ed9df6b6cc/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TwigEnvironmentPass.php#L49) process and I am quite sure the callable are being included there.

Do you have any idea what the problem is or how I might troubleshoot it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can see the results of the problem when you do `lint:twig` like is done here: https://travis-ci.org/zikula/core/jobs/623444067#L860

Comment: It is unusual for services in bundles to be autowired.  Typically you would manually define them in AdminModule/Resources/config/services.yaml.  I don't have a recent test case with bundles handy but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @Cerad - thank you for taking the time to respond. I had read so many of your answers here and have great respect.

Comment: @Cerad I will try to manually wire the services again and let you know.

Comment: ok - I've found that the point of failure is that we are decorating the `Twig/Environment` class/service (here: https://github.com/zikula/core/blob/614c8ec02d9291bc0a584bdeaef64199c1d8baf3/src/system/ThemeModule/Resources/config/services.yml#L97-L102). So, If I eliminate the decorating service definition, then the extensions are all added as expected. So apparently we are decorating incorrectly. What is the proper method to decorate?

Comment: Looks like they are trying to add an event dispatcher to the twig service.  Never tried anything like that.  Good luck.

Comment: they == me. yes, that's the idea. it worked well in symfony 3.

Comment: is your engine meant to always replace twig? if so, don't use `decorate` but make `Twig\Environment: [yourclass]`, and `[yourclass]: ... alias: twig`, which hopefully works. I strongly believe, `decorates` implies semantics which your class does **not** fulfill (specifically: it doesn't implement the decorator pattern). Read carefully: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The real question I was asking without realizing it was, "What is the correct way to override `Twig\Environment` with a child class?"**

The correct answer was to define the services in the same exact way as the original. (Symfony uses xml as a default though, so I had to convert). So this is the correct definition:

```
# override TwigBundle's Twig\Environment definition with Zikula's own child class
# see vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/twig.xml
twig:
    class: Zikula\ThemeModule\Bridge\Twig\EventEnabledTwigEngine
    public: true
    arguments:
      $loader: '@twig.loader'
      $options: []
    calls:
      - [setEventDispatcher, ['@event_dispatcher']]
      - [addGlobal, ['app', '@twig.app_variable']]
      - [addRuntimeLoader, ['@twig.runtime_loader']]
    configurator: ['@twig.configurator.environment', 'configure']
Twig_Environment: '@twig'
Twig\Environment: '@twig'
```

you can see how this is a copy of Symfony's:

```
    <service id="twig" class="Twig\Environment" public="true">
        <argument type="service" id="twig.loader" />
        <argument /> <!-- Twig options -->
        <call method="addGlobal">
            <argument>app</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="twig.app_variable" />
        </call>
        <call method="addRuntimeLoader">
            <argument type="service" id="twig.runtime_loader" />
        </call>
        <configurator service="twig.configurator.environment" method="configure" />
    </service>
    <service id="Twig_Environment" alias="twig" />
    <service id="Twig\Environment" alias="twig" />
```

and also see how it differs from @Jakumi's suggestion above:

```
Twig\Environment: Your\Class\Name
Your\Class\Name: # NO DECORATES!!!
   arguments: ...
   calls: ...
twig: Your\Class\Name # maybe setting it via alias is effective...
```

Many thanks to @Cerad and @Jakumi for your assistance in solving the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not quite sure, how the dependency injection decoration works *exactly*.

The dependency injection decoration doesn't make you write a proper decorator (since it can't be checked anyway), however, there are some indicators that it's no decorator.

Prime indicator: The decorating class doesn't depend on the decorated class, as in: it is not required as a parameter to `__construct()` or injected otherwise.

Reasoning: decorators should be usable in a cascading/chainable manner, essentially, decorators should be used like this (doesn't work in your case!):

```
$instance = new Decorator2(new Decorator1(new DecoratedClass()));
```

and decorator (methods) should on average look like this:

```
class Decorator {
   protected $inner;
   public function __construct(DecoratedClass $inner) {
       $this->inner = $inner;
   }
   public function someMethod($someParam) {
       // do something before, maybe change $someParam
       $returnValue = $this->inner->someMethod($someParam);
       // do something after, maybe change $returnValue  
       return $returnValue;
   }
}
```

The [symfony page on decorating](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) actually says most of this, directly or indirectly (references [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)).

As far as I can tell, every class would have to properly add all functions of the decorated class (annoying AF) as in: call it on the inner object.

Now, one approach might be to say: "well, I don't really care about actually decorating, I just want my class to be used instead of the twig environment!"

In which case, you should actively replace it with your class, as I indicated in my comment (services.yaml):

```
services:
    Twig\Environment: Your\Class\Name
    Your\Class\Name: # NO DECORATES!!!
       arguments: ...
       calls: ...
    twig: Your\Class\Name # maybe setting it via alias is effective...
```

Which *should* lead to your class being used whenever something requires either a `Twig\Environment` or `twig` or your class specifically.

However, in decorate-cases, your class should decorate the *class* it extends, and not the alias that class has.

Comment: Thanks Jakumi. As I said to @Cerad above, I've read many of your posts in the past and have great respect. With that said, I am trying to work on this and will get back to you. My first attempts did not succeed. I'll be back. thanks!

Comment: I set the config like you suggest (please see here: https://github.com/zikula/core/pull/3991/commits/8014c227e80898d3eddf9ca9fc8b15eb69c4e15e#diff-dc5b851362e25ee3c9ae1e85d59beb36R109-R118) but it is not yet working: using `debug:container twig` produces `Fatal error: Uncaught ...\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "Zikula\RoutesModule\Helper\ViewHelper" has a dependency on a non-existent service "twig.loader".` So this means the `twig.loader` service is no longer being created or aliased correctly. Which is very odd. Hoping you have additional insight. thank you in advance!

Comment: @craigh the error is in an entirely different module. but the error is weird still. I assume the error didn't occur before ... ?

Comment: apparently `twig.loader` only is added, if the `twig` service id exists, I'm just guessing at this point. trying to add `alias: twig` to your service might make a difference ... or just dropping the line entirely perhaps ... ;o/

Comment: right now I wonder, if setting your class via compiler pass would be better, and maybe a compilerpass like https://github.com/symfony/twig-bundle/blob/a684f9439ed7ed910d168fa6b6b246ed9df6b6cc/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TwigEnvironmentPass.php which instead just sets your class via `setClass` on the `$definition` like in here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/definitions.html#class ...

Comment: I wondered the same about the compiler pass. I'll give that a try tomorrow and get back to you.